# An ontology for describing a person at a specific time is in a specific location

Tags: owl, ontology

I am new to ontology and OWL. I want to describe that a person is located in a place in a specific time. How can I do this with OWL?
I defined three concepts: `person`, `place` and `time`. and two object property: `IsLocatedIn(person,place)`, `AtTime(person,time)`, but it's not what I want.

Comment: n-ary relations is the way to go, options how to do this in OWL are explained here: https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're searching for is [reification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science)#RDF_and_OWL). Reification is a KR technique that allows you to assert something smarter than a simple "subject-predicate-object" statement. This is usually done by first defining a "meta-statement" and then asserting anything you want about such meta-statement.

In your example, you could define a meta-concept instantiated as `LocationAtTime(l)` (using your notation), and then refer to it using three object properties: `IsLocated(person,l)`, `LocatedAt(l,time)`, `LocatedIn(l,place)`.